# How to pass string value to another react component and get some response from that component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to delete customer. I have created view for delete dialog box using Semantic UI.

In my customer view there is a list of customer with Edit and Delete Buttons.
On delete button click I want to open  view and pass a string "customer" to the Delete.js .

In delete I want to check the string value
In Delete view if user click Delete or Cancel button send back true or false value

In Customer check the value and perform task

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AddCustomer from './AddCustomer';
import Delete from './Delete';

export default class Customer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        deleteTitle:"customer",
        isLoaded: false,
        formClose:false,
        isAddCustomer:false,
        isEditCustomer:false,
        singleCustomer:[],
        users: []
    }
}

//fetch data 
componentDidMount() {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Origin','https://localhost:44387');

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        myHeader
    };

    fetch(customerApi, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                users: result,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: false,
                error
            });
        }
    )


}

//Delete Customer

onDeleteCustomer = customerId => {

    //On button click
    //Send deleteTitle to Delete.js and open Model view a dialog box 
    //------<Delete pass deleteTitle here to delete.js/>
    //get retun value true or false
    //then delete customer 

    const{users} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        users: users.filter(customer => customer.customerId !== customerId)
    });

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/'+customerId;

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'DELETE',
        headers:myHeader

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({

            })
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    console.log("Edit customer");

    let customerForm;
    if (this.state.isEditCustomer || this.state.isAddCustomer){
        console.log("In render")
        customerForm = <AddCustomer onAddFormSubmit={this.onAddFormSubmit} singleCustomer={this.state.singleCustomer}/>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {customerForm}
            <Table celled textAlign='center'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body >
                    {
                        users.map(user => (
                            <Table.Row key={user.customerId}>

                                <Table.Cell>{user.customerId}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.address}</Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='blue' onClick = {()=>this.onEditCustomer(user.customerId)}>Edit</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                <Button color='red' onClick = 
 {()=>this.onDeleteDetails(user.customerId)}>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                            </Table.Row>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table.Body>

                <Table.Footer>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='5'>
                            No of Pages
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Footer>
            </Table>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Delete View

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class EditCustomer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title:"",
        deleteResponce:false
    };
    console.log("In delete")
    console.log("Value"+this.props.deleteTitle)
    if(this.props.deleteTitle.value === "customer"){

        this.setState({
            title:this.props.deleteTitle
        });
    }
    //And same for Product,store,sales 
    //I want get string like customer so on Delete dialog box the title will be 
    //"Delete customer"
}

//On cancel button click close Create user form
closeCreateForm = () => {
    console.log("Clicked")
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: false })
}

//Open Create new Customer form
openCreateCustomer = () => {
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: true })
}

trueDeleteResponce = event =>{

        const value = event.target.value;

        if(!value){
            this.setState({deleteResponce:false})
        }else{
            this.setState({deleteResponce:true})
        }

        this.props.onDeleteDetails(this.state.deleteResponce);

}

render() {
    const title = "Delete "+ this.state.title;

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal closeOnTriggerMouseLeave={false} trigger={
                <Button color='red'  onClick={this.openCreateCustomer}>
                    {title}
        </Button>
            } open={this.state.showCreateForm}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    Are you sure?
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Content>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <Button floated='right' icon labelPosition='right' color='red'
                            value = 'true'
                            onClick = {this.trueDeleteResponce} 
                            >
                              <Icon name='close'/>
                                   Delete
                        </Button>
                        <Button floated='right' color='black'
                            value = 'false'
                            onClick = {this.trueDeleteResponce}
                        >Cancel</Button>

                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                </Modal.Content>

            </Modal>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may make others easier to understand your problem?

Comment: I want to pass string value to a Delete.js and on delete button click i want call onDeleteustomer in customer

Comment: @RahulWaghmare.. you have defined a lot of states and functions unnecessarily. I can show you a neat way of doing it, with offline data. let me know, if you would want that.

Comment: @Barun Patro yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go..
Let me know, if i can be of more help..

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-6plq9

EDIT:

Just adding a few details.

So lets focus on the **delete functionality** for now, cause Edit is just similar.

In the table, each row takes a key **prop(Customer Id)**. Now you need to pass the this property to the next Component(Delete.js) in order to remove it.

In my case i didn't need it. because I am not sharing the actual customers array with the children. So the child component(Delete.js) won't be able to modify it. It can only ask the parent component to do it.

So i have kept the customers array and the **deleteCustomers** action with the parent only. I am passing the same to the child, so that it can invoke this method, when needed.

There is another method, **removeCustomer**, it just shows the modal and then sets the active customerId. when deleteCustomer is called, it removes the active Customer Id from the list.